# Spark Scala Seq append. Should I broadcast the variable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I´m definning a variable as an empty `Seq()` where i´m going to append elements from a `Map(String, String)` rdd.

The variable is declared like that:

```
var list: Seq[(String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String, String)] = Seq()
```

Then, iterating over rdd elements, I append in the var list the result that match some condition. It is something like that:

```
if (condition) {list :+= ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")}
```

When I try it in local I get the desired output but my problem comes when trying to execute in the cluster, where I am getting the empty list.

It seems this is not working in parallel computation. Should I broadcast the variable before appending on it or maybe take the variable to the driver with a `collect()` at the end ??

Thanks !!

Comment: Can you include your Spark code to the question?

Comment: Mutability and spark are a recipe for disaster. You should use `Accumulator`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/util/AccumulatorV2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the spark Documentation

> Normally, when a function passed to a Spark operation (such as map or
> reduce) is executed on a remote cluster node, it works on separate
> copies of all the variables used in the function. **These variables are
> copied to each machine, and no updates to the variables on the remote
> machine are propagated back to the driver program.** Supporting general,
> read-write shared variables across tasks would be inefficient.
> However, Spark does provide two limited types of shared variables for
> two common usage patterns: broadcast variables and accumulators.

Please look at highlighted part in the above text. as it said tasks/executors will not propagate changes back to driver app. so your list will be empty.

Before Going to solution. First, let's understand broadcast variables and accumulators

1. Broadcast Variables

> Broadcast variables allow the programmer to keep a **read-only
> variable** cached on each machine rather than shipping a copy of it
> with tasks.The data broadcasted this way is cached in serialized form
> and deserialized before running each task.

These broadcast variables are read-only variables you cannot update them. In your case you are updating `list :+= ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")` which you cannot achieve this by broadcasting

2. Accumulators

> Accumulators are variables that are only “added” to through an
> **associative and commutative operation** and can therefore be efficiently supported in parallel. They can be used to implement
> counters (as in MapReduce) or sums.

your task can be achieved using accumulators.you can write a custom accumulator by extending **AccumulatorV2** API and encapsulate your list structure inside it
and then you can register accumulator in spark context as `sc.register(objectReference, "MyAccumulator")`

Note :

> Accumulators do not change the lazy evaluation model of Spark. If they
> are being updated within an operation on an RDD, their value is only
> updated once that RDD is computed as part of an action. Consequently,
> accumulator updates are not guaranteed to be executed when made within
> a lazy transformation like map()

Comment: Ok !! Its working now in the cluster using acumulators. It comes to my mind if it would have been enough with defining my var as val ListBuffer ... I´ll try !

Comment: @Alexnuru please feel free to upvote or accept answer. if it answers your question.